# Royalities CIP 27

Tags: nft, metadata

I followed the  CIP 27 for implementing royalities:

https://cardanoupdates.com/commits/facb8aa0ad9aa41f1a047b2000674fdea2162e71

Mint no name token with the policy then burn it wit the metadata incluiding royalities info:

for example:

https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/transaction/2471b2b3092744b21ee7eb45f68e37f753f834ab911567219d9127e399f4ba9a?tab=metadata

```
   {
   addr: [
      "addr1q88604np2z4hkl9a78dhuxasnssrxzk5kz497yvw4wq7jjp7vt8s8tygau8",
      "fl40vg3t7gxdzkq7uxl8sqmaqqkdxca0sg9y"
   ],
       rate: "0.1"
}
```

then I burn the token.

My doubt is if should I add the same data that I added in the initial mint/burn as a field in the standard 721 metadata? so  the marketplace can fetch this field, or if it is not needed, i am guessing it should not be needed otherwise the initial mint/burn mechanism would be not needed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't add your 721 data here. The above example is all you should have, and then burn the token.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask how do you know this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Because I run Cardano minting vending machines for artists and have done it dozens of times.. :)

I've also spoken with the person who initially wrote the 777 CIP proposal. You can find the details here:

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/116/files